# 'currentCtx' is undefined

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007, wss-3.0

While trying to create/upload a document in a document library, Ie throws the below exception

'currentCtx' is undefined

what it means and how to fix this?

Comment: I'm the only one facing this issue and it seems to be an issue with IE Settings, any clues?

Answer (score 0):

That's a javascript variable used in SharePoint menus and list views. It's defined at the top of core.js - if it is showing up as undefined you most likely have either a problem loading scripts or something on the page is causing the initialization scripts not to run correctly.